# How to get the index of the first space occurring before a particular character

Tags: java, string, parsing

I  have a file which has line in the format

```
xbox one    gaming-consoles:xbox-one-games:gaming-controllers
xbox one games  xbox-one-games
xbox 360 games  xbox-360-games:gaming-consoles
xbox 360    gaming-consoles:xbox-360-games:gaming-controllers
```

Now i want to split the lines in two parts . The logic of splitting is that it should be done at the first space before the character ':'

so the splited text should look like

```
xbox one             gaming-consoles:xbox-one-games:gaming-controllers
xbox one games       ox-one-games:gaming-controllers
xbox 360 games       xbox-360-games:gaming-consoles
```

and so on....

How can this be acheived ?

Comment: not sure if you can do it with a regex, but I would simply iterate over the string and save last found space. When I find a ":" I would split on the last found space

Comment: So, what will happen to `xbox one games  xbox-one-games`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lastIndexOf`to get the position within the string of the last space, then use `substring` to split the string into two different variables.

```
String s1 = "test string with lots of     spaces";
String s2 = s1.substring(0, s1.lastIndexOf(" "); //From the first character until the last space
String s3 = s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf(" ")+1); //Index of last space+1 to end.
System.out.println(s1 + "\n" + s2 + "\n" + s3);
```

Which gives the output of:

```
test string with lots of     spaces
test string with lots of
spaces
```

A small problem would be that the string containing the first half would still contain the whitespace at the end of the string, but could be easily mediated if needed with `trim`.

Comment: While this might be the solution for OP since the example strings have no spaces after `:`, this won't work for the current requirements: *The logic of splitting is that it should be done at the first space before the character `:`*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a regex to extract the second part of each line.

`(\\s[\\S]+)(?=:).+` will lookahead `(\\s[\\S]+)` to check if it followed by a `:`. `(\\s[\\S]+)` select the group that begins with a space `\s` and followed by nonspace characters `[\S]+`.

Here is the sample code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TestRegex {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String[] line = new String[] {
            "xbox one    gaming-consoles:xbox-one-games:gaming-controllers",
            "xbox one games  xbox-one-games",
            "xbox 360 games  xbox-360-games:gaming-consoles",
            "xbox 360    gaming-consoles:xbox-360-games:gaming-controllers "
        };

        String regex = "(\\s[\\S]+)(?=:).+";

        Pattern re = Pattern.compile(regex);

        for (String ln : line) {
            Matcher m = re.matcher(ln);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(0));
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> The logic of splitting is that it should be done at the first space before the character `:`

Use a positive lookahead based regex:

```
String s = "xbox one    gaming-consoles:xbox-one-games:gaming-controllers and more here";
String[] chunks = s.split(" ++(?=[^ :]*:)", 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chunks));
// => [xbox one, gaming-consoles:xbox-one-games:gaming-controllers and more here]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/x6rpBg)

The `split` will yield one (if no match is found) or 2 chunks (since the limit argument is passed, `2`). The split will happen at 1 or more spaces (see `" ++"`) that are followed with 0+ chars other than a space and `:` (see `[^ :]*`) followed with a `:`.